# Animate on table that is generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to apply a plugin on a certain table that is being generated dynamically through a php script. This is the plugin : [CLICK](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/01/04/animating-html-ranking-tables-with-javascript.html#f1Example)

Now from what i read in the comments i should `You first need some form of server side component, say a PHP script, which generates the html table from the data in the database. Then pass the URL of this PHP script into a jQuery ajax call. In the "success" callback, set the innerHTML of some holding div to the response of the ajax call, then select this newly created DOM table element and put it into the plugin.
Hope that makes sense!`

Here's what i got so far.

HTML

```
<div class="testin">
<script>
testin();
</script>
</div>
```

JS

```
function testin(){
    var load = $.get('functions.php',{gameNo:"1",function:"testin"});
    $(".testin").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".testin").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".testin").html(res);
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
    });
}
```

php

```
if($_GET['function']=="testin")
{

    echo '<table class="template" style="display:none"><thead><tr><th>Game Name</th><th>Round</th><th>Player Name</th><th>Target Name</th><th>Shot Number Now</th><th>Shot Score So Far</th><th>Rank</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
    $gamenumber = $_GET['gameNo'];
    echo'<table border="1" class="actualTable"><tr><th>Game Name</th><th>Round</th><th>Player Name</th><th>Target Name</th><th>Shot Number Now</th><th>Shot Score So Far</th><th>Rank</th></tr>';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Round WHERE match_id='$gamenumber' ORDER BY round_name")
    or die(mysql_error());
    $i=1;   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $tempSnumber = getcurrentshot($row['round_id'],$row['player_id']);
        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$gamenumber.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['round_name'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['player_id'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['target_name'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$tempSnumber.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['round_score'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        echo'</tr>';
        $i++;
    }


    echo'</table>';
}
```

The function fills the div just fine. I also create the `template` table in the php script.

Now my problem is how to invoke the plugin and what should i pass ass objects?
Invocation is like `$(oldTableElement).rankingTableUpdate(newTableElement)` but i'm confused due to the fact that it's being generated dynamically.

I'm new to JS so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would put your javascript outside the div with class "testin".
Below you JS function you can add the jquery call like in the code below.
See this link for more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $("table tr").on( "click", function() {
     //your custom code goes here.
   });
});
```

What this does is make sure then any element that matches the "table tr" will get an click handler, no matter when it gets created.

Comment: I see, from what i understand it works like this: `$(old table class).rankingTableUpdate(new table class)` and it fades in and out between the two tables from what i tested in JSfiddle. Since it's generated by JS through a php how should i adjust the invocation ?

Comment: If I understood the explanation of the plugin correctly it's meant to animate transitions between two tables (which represent two moments in time if you will). So in the click handler function you should first check if there is already a table and then execute the rankingTableUpdate. I would suggest you add a parameter to you php script, like say a number. Then in the php script use that number to generate a class for your table (like "table1", "table2"),...

Since you know in your js which number were given to the php you can then use code like this:$("table1").rankingTableUpdate("table2");

Comment: I put the generated table in a hidden div and have another table as default at start. Then in the success function after i call the php script and fill the div (hidden) with the table i call the function and replace the template table with the actualTable(produced by php). 
Problem is that it changes the table id so in the next call of the function there's no template table to fill with the actual table.

Comment: to fix that you could reset the id of the table with:
 $("#TABLE_ID").attr("id","NEW_TABLE_ID");

Comment: Issue is that after the run, there's two tables with id="actualTable".